# Find position of last Non Null element in a list in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following values in my MySQL DB

```
Date        High_Low_Price
5/18/2017   302
5/19/2017   315.3
5/22/2017   Null
5/23/2017   Null
5/24/2017   Null
5/25/2017   Null
5/26/2017   Null
5/29/2017   Null
```

and I have create the a list in the below format

```
List<db1> StockData = new List<db1>(); 
db1 newStock = new db1();
newStock.High_Low_Price = (double)reader["High_Low_Price"];
StockData.Add(newStock);
```

How can I find the position of the last not null element (i.e. i) in the list. When I mean last element I am refering to the 315.3 of High_Low_Price on the 5/19/2017.

the Null values in High_Low_Price column will keep varying in size. How would i then find the last date which has a value in this list ?

EDIT: i need two things, The Date and the position.

Comment: Are all the `null` values at the end of the list? Or can they occur in the middle?

Comment: Can you just eliminate nulls (and sort) in the underlying query?

Comment: First off: `(int)reader["High_Low_Price"];` will throw an Exception as you can't cast `DBNull.Value` to `int`. Its not clear what/how you are wanting to do this. You have a `reader` instance, I assume its an open data reader. Do you want to iterate over the returned results until you find a `null` value or are you trying to create a new query to return only the last date with a `null` value?

Comment: "the Null values in High_Low_Price column will keep varying in size." - say what?

Comment: @MattBurland: If they occur in the middle (and not the end), then that means there is another non-null value below them, which would then be the "last non-null value", which is what OP is after.

Comment: @MattBurland: They would always be at the end of the list

Comment: @pm100: I meant there would be more dates where I could have null values for High_Low_Price

Comment: @Flater: Yes, I know that. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Falter: Null values would always occuer at the end of the list

Comment: @AlexK.: I have other columns too in the db that are included in the query. i have just shared a part of the table to keep it simple :) Thats why i cant eliminate the nulls in the underlying query

Comment: @PrateekDaniels Many of the answers here get the first non-null value but in your question you seem to be wanting to know the position of the element as opposed to its value is that the case?

Comment: @univ: I need the position and the date

Comment: @PrateekDaniels Sounds good, I just posted an answer based on that info

Comment: @PrateekDaniels Which approach did you end up taking?

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = StockData.Where(lst=>lst.High_Low_Price!=null).OrderByDescending(lst=>lst.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date;
```

Comment: that returns the row, not the position

Comment: I guess he wants the date, so modified it

Comment: Can throw exception if `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` in future.

Comment: Thats correct, we should leave something for Prateek to work on as well.

Comment: @VarunMehta:Visual Studio shows the following error : IEnnumerable <db1> does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDesc' and no extension method 'OrderByDesc' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<db1>' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly refernce)

Comment: @VarunMehta: Its  .OrderByDescending, but it gives me an error saying : the result of the expression would alsway be true since a value of type double is never equal to 'null' of type 'double'

Comment: (double)reader["High_Low_Price"] will give you an exception if reader["High_Low_Price"] is null as well. Are you sure this is the way the list is getting stored? You can compare it with Zero, if its storing it as 0.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var row = StockData.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.High_Low_Price.HasValue);

if (row != null) // In case above query don't return anything 
                 // cause all rows have blank High_Low_Price 
{
    var result = row.ModifiedDate;
}
```

Comment: OrderByDesending - It says it cant find a definition for that

Comment: Namespace:   System.Linq

Comment: Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)

Comment: I have added " using System.Linq;", still doesnt work

Comment: By bad. Its `OrderByDescending`

Comment: x.High_Low_Price != null - It says this will always be true, since value of type is double

Comment: Replace it with `x.High_Low_Price.HasValue` Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int position = StockData.IndexOf(
              StockData.Where(lst=>lst.High_Low_Price!=null).OrderByDesc(lst=>lst.Date).FirstOrDefault()
            );

var lastDate = StockData[position]?.Date;
```

Comment: Since the OP's code doesn't populate a `Date` field, I wouldn't assume it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is already in order from the original database query:

```
var idx = StockData.Select((data,idx) => new { data, idx})
                   .Where(x => x.data.High_Low_Price != null).FirstOrDefault()?.i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that type of High_Low_Price is  nullable, like 'double?'

```
var lastDate = StockData.Last(x => x.High_Low_Price.HasValue).Date;
```

Comment: How would i use this incase the value is double ? Thanks :)

Comment: It will work for any nullable type like 'double?', 'int?', 'decimal?' :)

Comment: It throws an error : 'double' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue'

Comment: As I say'd, only for nullable types, I don't think your list can have nulls if field type is not nullable, but in case it not works, you can try `StockData.Last(x => x.High_Low_Price != null)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in one of your comments that Null values are always at the end of the list then assuming that's the case and since you only want the position of the element and its date a naive approach to solving this would be to just do

```
        var i = 0;
        var pos = 0;
        DateTime? date = null;
        while (i < StockData.Count && StockData.ElementAt(i)?.High_Low_Price != null )
        {
            pos = i;
            date = StockData.ElementAt(i).Date;
            i++;
        }
```